# passing form name dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function validate_login(form){
 alert(form);
 var formName = form.name;
 alert(formName);

 if(!validate_username(form)){
    return false;
 } else{
  return validate_password(form);
 }
}
```

i called the above function in an external javascript as

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post" class="message" id="login_form" name ="login_form" onsubmit="javascript:return validate_login(this.form)">
```

but alert(form) shows an alert having output 'undefined'  and alert(fornName) is not showing an alert. help me pleasee..

Comment: "javascript:" is useless

Comment: `this` refers to the form.  `this.form` is trying to access the `form` property on the `form`... probably not what you're after

Comment: The second alert cannot show, because you try to access the property `name` of the undefined object `form`

Comment: Side note: if/else can be replaced by `return validate_username(form) && validate_password(form);`.

Comment: For debugging purposes it is better to use console.log or a Javascript Debugger like the Chrome Developer Tools!

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the form correctly, pass only `this`.
What you're trying to do is passing the property `form` of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validate_login(this.form)"
```

to

```
onsubmit="return validate_login(this)"
```

---

**Running Example**

```js
function validate_login(form) {
  alert(form);
  var formName = form.name;
  alert(formName);

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post" class="message" id="login_form" name="login_form" onsubmit="return validate_login(this)">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```